# SQL query and table joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table Alpha with the below columns

Table: ALPHA

```
AID |  ZIP_CODE | VID | IN_DATE    
=================================
100 | 48084     | 1G  | 2020-07-20
---------------------------------- 
102 | 28262     | 1M  | 2020-01-21
---------------------------------  
103 | 28277     | 3G  | 2020-05-12
----------------------------------
104 | 40004     | 1N  | 2020-10-20
```

Table: BETA

```
AID | OPEN_AMT | ACTUAL_AMT 
----------------------------
100 | 5800     | 5900        
102 | 2000     | 3000       
103 | 3400     | 3200
104 | 2000     | 2200
```

Table: CHARLIE

```
AID | AUCSAID
--------------
100 | 2001
100 | 2002
100 | 2003
102 | 2002
102 | 2001
103 | 2001
103 | 2002
```

My query result should look like the below: (IN_DATE greater than apr 2020 and show count of AUCSAID)

```
AID  |  IN_DATE   | ZIP_CODE  | VID | OPEN_AMT  | ACTUAL_AMT | count(AUCSAID)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
100  | 2020-07-20 | 48084     | 1G  | 5800      | 5900       | 3
103  | 2020-05-12 | 28277     | 3G  | 3400      | 3200       | 2
```

I want the ORACLE SQLs that returns the above. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you even tried anything????

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a join with a count on the extra table:

```
select a.*, b.open_amt, b.close_amt,
       (select count(*) from charlie c where c.aid = a.aid) as cnt
from alpha a join
     beta b
     on a.aid = b.aid
where a.indate_date >= date '2020-04-01';
```

Comment: what about IN_DATE greater than apr 2020 condition?

Comment: thanks. i have updated my question. you see there is a record 104 which i not present in the Charlie table. I dont want that to show up in my result. If i run the above query i get a row for 104 with count as 0 in my result. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
select
    a.aid,
    a.in_date,
    a.zip_code,
    a.vid,
    b.open_amt,
    b.close_amt,
    c.cnt
from
    alpha a
    join beta b on (a.aid = b.aid)
    join (select aid, count(1) as cnt from charlie group by aid) c on (c.aid. = a.aid)
where
    a.in_date >= date '2020-04-01';
```

Thanks.